# Cannot find "valid home for jdk" in intellij idea

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk, sdk

I'm trying to setup an SDK for intellij idea and I can't find the home for jdk as the error put it.

In the terminal this is what I get

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
```

I tried to run

`$ whereis java`

and none of the paths are valid

then I found the jvm folder in usr/lib/jvm none of those worked either.

this is the output of

`$ ls -lh /usr/lib/jvm/`

[image]

I just ran another command

```
$ update-alternatives --list java
```

Output was

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

In idea, the sdk selector will only go upto the /bin but the internal files don't appear and in the file explorer I can see the java file but clicking it does nothing nor can I directly copy it's path as I get the error:

"Specified path cannot be found"

Also ran

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --display java
```

Output

```
java - auto mode
link best version is /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
link java is /usr/bin/java
slave java.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java - priority 1081
slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java - priority 1091
slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

Comment: Please run this `sudo update-alternatives --display java`  from your terminal and post the results lets see where your java is!

Comment: Updated with the command you asked for and another one that I found .

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add `JAVA_HOME` to your `.bashrc` file.

1. Edit the:

   ```
   gedit ~/.bashrc
   ```
2. Add the following lines:

   ```
   ## JAVA_HOME
   export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64"
   export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
   ```
3. Add it to the `/etc/environemnt` file with:

   ```
   echo "JAVA_HOME=\"/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64\"" | sudo tee -a /etc/environment
   ```
4. Close and open a new terminal.
5. If all doesn't work then:

   1. Launch Intellij
   2. Press: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

      - The go to `Platform Settings -> SDKs`
      - click to add the path for your `java sdk`

      [image]

Now your IntelliJ should be able to see it.

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: Updated answer please see the update

Comment: I've been in the configure SDK panel from the start, trying to locate the JDK directory. I still  get the same error.

Comment: I just purged all traces of java in my system and did a clean install of openjdk-8 and got it to work currently the path is /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error because I had changed my jdk and my Intellij was still referring to the location where I had my previous jdk. All I did was go to `File -> Project Structure`. Go to `SDKs` under Platform Settings in the project structure dialog box. After this, you just navigate to the place where you have installed the jdk home directory. (For me, it was `/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_271`). And just do `Apply` then `Ok`. This error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, becauese I changed the folder(directory) for download.
I solved it, go to 'File -> Project Structure' and 'Project Settings -> Project', SDK : "download folder -> jbr". That's all I did.